# Configuring ActiveMQ 5.16.0 web console with specific IP address

Tags: activemq-classic

I just installed ActiveMQ 5.16.0 on Linux machine OEL7.8. I was able to open console using `http://localhost:8161`, but when I am using `http://IP:8161` on the same machine the console page is not opening in the browser. Is there any config to be done in `jetty.xml` file or `activemq.xml` file?

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who may have this same question in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `host` property on `jettyPort` bean in `conf/jetty.xml`, e.g.:

```xml
    <bean id="jettyPort" class="org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsolePort" init-method="start">
        <property name="host" value="IP"/>
        <property name="port" value="8161"/>
    </bean>
```